# Postgresql update with values

Tags: sql, postgresql

lets say i have table like this (new_table) (all field is not-null constraints):

```
id    name        km_unit
1     honda       1000
2     toyota      2000
3     bmw         1000
4     wuling      1500
```

i want to update the table with insert with this query:

```
insert into new_table(id,km_unit) values
(1,20000),
(2,20000),
(3,200000),
(4,200000)
ON CONFLICT (id) 
DO 
   update SET km_unit = EXCLUDED.km_unit
```

but it return error like this :

```
null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint
```

the question is how to update the existing km_unit field if the id is same with values that i inserted?
can i update the table without writing name field in the values?

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with the UPDATE part. You are trying to insert rows with a NULL value for the `name` column, but you have a `not null` constraint on that column. If you **only** want to update the rows use an UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you don't actually want to insert anything, so use an UPDATE statement:

```
update new_table dl
  set km_unit = v.km_unit
from (
  values 
    (1,20000),
    (2,20000),
    (3,200000),
    (4,200000)
) as v(id, km_unit)
where v.id = dl.id
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . But why would the code in the question generate a `NOT NULL` violation.  No rows are being inserted.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I assume because it first tries to insert the rows and the NOT NULL check is done before the unique constraint check.

Answer (score 2):

**NOT NULL constraint**

When the NOT NULL constraint is defined for a column, a row containing the null value in that column cannot be added, nor can a row be updated so as to set the null value in that column. A column for which the NOT NULL constraint is defined must have a definite value in every row. An attempt to set the null value in such a column results in a constraint violation.

In your case it means the column `NAME` should have a value.

Comment: can i use the existing values in the tabel without typing it all, like this:

on conflict (id)
update set name = new_table.name, km_unit = excluded.km_unit

Comment: I don't think so. ON CONFLICT works to guarantee UNIQUE ENTRY and has nothing to do with NOT NULL. But you can ALTER your NAME column and set a DEFAULT VALUE for it.